# Finding gaps in sequence numbers

Tags: sequence, teradata, self-join

Boiling this down to its simplest terms, I have a two column table of the form:
|PK|SEQ|

The PK value is a domain key. The SEQ column represents the sequence number delivered to me by an upstream system. Unfortunately, the upstream system can occasionally miss a sequence item. For example, I might see:

|PK|SEQ|
|a|0|
|a|1|
|a|3|

so for domain key value a, I am "missing" sequence number 2.
Here's my first attempt at the SQL (which works, assuming I have transposed correctly) in Oracle.

However it does not work in Teradata. I get Error 3807, Object e1 does not exist.

```
SELECT
    e1.pk,
 
    e1.seq,

    e2.seq
FROM
    my_table   e1,
    my_table   e2
WHERE
    e1.pk = e2.pk
    AND e2.seq = (
        SELECT
            ehash
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    e3.pk  ,
                    MIN(e3.seq) AS ehash
                FROM
                    my_table  e3
                WHERE
                    1 = 1
                    AND e3.pk = e1.pk

                    and e3.seq > e1.seq

                    group by e3.pk having min(e3.seq) > e1.seq
            )
    )
    and e2.seq -1 > e1.seq
```

I presume that I have the name scoping incorrect somehow, but I can't figure it out.

There might well be OLAP or or other functions that could help me, but I am not acquainted with them. So if there is a better way of achieving the case to meet my requirement, please bring it on.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that you can't reference your e1 table in a derived table inside your correlated sub-query.  Not a solution, but that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, yes that goes some way to explaining it. Disappointing, of course. But at least that stops me from beating my head against the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is simple to do with OLAP / QUALIFY

```
SELECT pk, seq SEQ1, LEAD(seq) OVER (PARTITION BY pk ORDER BY seq) AS SEQ2
FROM my_table
QUALIFY SEQ2 <> SEQ1+1;
```

Or if you wanted to use correlated scalar subquery, then put it in the expression list for the SELECT

```
SELECT
    e1.pk,
    e1.seq,
                (
                SELECT
                    MIN(e3.seq) AS ehash
                FROM
                    my_table  e3
                WHERE
                     e3.pk = e1.pk
                    and e3.seq > e1.seq
                ) AS seq2
FROM
    my_table   e1
WHERE
    seq2-1 > e1.seq;
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I hadn't thought of putting it into the expression list like that. Clever! And yes, I suspected that LEAS might be the way to go. You have made it quite clear.